# Mathematica demonstration for Markov convergence tracking effect on input distributions in 2D (or 3D)

Tags: markov-chains, demonstrations

Is there a mathematica demo that demonstrates the convergence of Markov chains in 2 dimensions, and possibly 3, as follows?

In 2 dimensions, start with the interval determined by $x + y = 1$ for which $x,y \geq 0$ (segment connecting [0,1] and [1,0]), i.e. the collection of possible initial probability distributions for the Markov chain. Use a 2 x 2 stochastic matrix $P$, say with first row, $\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}$ and second row $\frac{1}{4}, \frac{3}{4}$ (where these values can be set with sliders).

Illustrate the changes of the segment by repeatedly left multiplying the (distribution) vectors $(x,y)$ in this segment with increasing powers of P. Add sliders to show how the segment changes under these multiplications and converges to one of the points on the segment, i.e. the limiting distribution $\Pi = (\Pi_1,\Pi_2)$.

Is there code available that could be adapted for this purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a way to visualize a stochastic matrix $\mathbf{M}$ operating on initial random distributions $\pi_i = (t_i, 1-t_i)$ on the line segment. $\mathbf{M}$ has adjustable probabilities $p,q$. It shows the convergence of any point $\pi_i$ to a single limiting distribution $\pi_\infty = \lim_{n \to \infty}\pi_i\mathbf{M}^n$ with repeat operation of the transition matrix:

```
segment = Line[{{0, 1}, {1, 0}}];
points = RandomPoint[segment, 50];
Manipulate[
 With[{mtx = {{p, 1 - p}, {q, 1 - q}}},
  ListAnimate[
   Graphics[{Point[#], segment}, Frame -> True, 
      PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}] & /@ 
    NestList[Function[{pts}, pts.mtx] /@ # &, points, 20]]
  ]
 , {p, 0, 1}, {q, 0, 1}]
```

[image: convergence of points on the line segment]

Comment: Thanks! This is indeed what I had in mind.